# Como puedo anidar dos operadores terniarios?

Tags: java

Espero que puedan ayudarme! Necesito anidar estos 2 opeadores terniarios los cuales son:

```
Boolean val1 = (parameterIn.get("amount")!=null )
                && (util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue()))) 
                        ||(parameterIn.get("amount")== null)?  true : false;
```

Segundo Terniario:

```
Boolean val2=(parameterIn.get("date")!=null)
                    && (util.validateDate((String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue())))
                    || (util.dateNull((String)parameterIn.get("date")))? true : false;
```

Comment: Mas que anidar, sería juntarlos lógicamente con `&&`; pero puede ser conveniente separarlos para notificar claramente al usuario de la situación.

Answer (score 1):

```
(condicion1) 
    ? ((condicion2) ? Resultado2True : Resultado2False) // Este es el resultado1True de la primera conddición
    : ((condicion3) ? Resultado3True : Resultado3False); // Este es el resultado1False de la primera conddición
```

Tu código sería:

```
Boolean val1 = ((parameterIn.get("amount")!=null ) && (util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue())) ||(parameterIn.get("amount")== null)))
    // Acá, si la conficion1 es true, procederá a realizar la segunda condidicional que está abajo
    ?  (Boolean (val2=(parameterIn.get("date")!=null) && (util.validateDate((String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue()))) || (util.dateNull((String)parameterIn.get("date"))))
       ? true // Acá te devuelve el resultado true de la segunda condición
       : false) // Acá te devuelve el resultado false de la segunda condición
    : false
  // Debes colocar la segunda condición con su respuesta true y false dentro de paréntesis 
  // Identado así para que sea más fácil de leer
```

[Operadores ternarios anidados Wiki-Base](https://wiki-base.com/7779254-java-ternary-operator)

Comment: Si bien la lógica puede ser correcta, siempre me ha parecido muy innecesario asignar `true` o `false` tras hacer una comprobación... que ya te va a devolver true o false. Básicamente estás escribiendo `if (x == true) { val1 = true} else { val1 = false }`... y eso es exactamente lo que devuelve la comprobación! Ignorad los ternarios, ignorad la lógica extraña y enrevesada, y usad `boolean val1 = check1 && check2 && check3 && check4 && check5`, y ya está. Para qué quieres comprobar si vas a asignar true o false, cuando la condición ya es exactamente lo que devuelve??

Answer (score 1):

Aunque técnicamente la respuesta de @JGames6351 responde correctamente a la pregunta... creo que esta pregunta parte de un error de base, me explico.

Básicamente se pregunta cómo se hace esto pero con ternarios

```
if (x == true) {
  val1 = true;
} else {  // x == false
  val1 = false;
}

if (y == true) {
  val2 = true;
} else {  // y == false
  val2 = false;
}

val3 == val1 && val2; // resultado del "anidamiento"
```

Ahora pregunto... realmente vale la pena hacer comprobaciones para asignar el resultado de dicha comprobación a continuación?? Desde mi punto de vista, queda mucho más claro si eliminamos los `if` y asignamos directamente:

```
boolean resultado = parameterIn.get("amount") != null && 
(
    util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue())) ||
    parameterIn.get("amount") == null
) &&
parameterIn.get("date") != null &&
(
    util.validateDate((String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue())) ||
    util.dateNull((String)parameterIn.get("date"))
)
```

---

Aun más sencillo y fácil de ver, si movemos la lógica a un método de utilidad. Recordad que **el código lo escribimos una vez, pero lo leemos un montón de veces más**! Cuanto más sencillo sea leer tu código, más fácil podrás depurarlo, arreglarlo y modificarlo:

```
bla blablabla(blabla) {
    // código
    boolean resultado = validateAmountAndDate(parameterIn);
    // más código
}


private boolean validateAmountAndDate(ClaseDelObjeto parameterIn) {
    return 
        parameterIn.get("amount") != null && 
        (
            util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue())) ||
            parameterIn.get("amount") == null
        ) &&
        parameterIn.get("date") != null &&
        (
            util.validateDate((String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue())) ||
            util.dateNull((String)parameterIn.get("date"))
        );
}
```

He intentado mantener las comprobaciones igual que estaban, pero hay algo que no entiendo en la pregunta... que es por qué se está haciendo primero
`parameterIn.get("amount") != null` y a continuación `parameterIn.get("amount") == null`.
Creo que debería revisarse un poco la implementación de esas comprobaciones, pero eso ya es otra historia.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola benito, primero que nada agradecer de tomarse el tiempo de contestar mi pregunta y sobre el parameterIn.get("amount") != null aqui esta mandando a llamar al Map con su respectiva clase en este caso esta el "amount" qué es llamado!

Comment: Correcto, @Carlosfernando, pero a continuación compruebas justo lo contrario: `||(parameterIn.get("amount")== null)`, siempre va a ser true una de las dos comprobaciones. Por cierto, recuerda que si una respuesta te es de ayuda (sea esta o la de jgames) lo correcto es marcarla como aceptada :)